# Why Covid-19 might end until September-October in Mexico?

Tags: covid-19, virus, statistics, data, length-of-time

This link was published ~8 hours ago https://www.razon.com.mx/mexico/epidemia-septiembre-pico-agosto/ (spanish) mention this

> The Undersecretary of Prevention and Health Promotion, Hugo López-Gatell, indicated that if the community mitigation measures are successful, the Covid-19 epidemic in the country will last longer, but there will be fewer cases, which it will prevent hospitals from collapsing.
>
> "We could very probably be arriving until September or October with this epidemic, with a maximum peak perhaps in the month of August," he said. For this, 80 percent of mild cases are expected, 15 percent that will require hospitalization and only five percent intensive therapy, the official explained.
>
> For his part, José Luis Alomía Zegarra, general director of Epidemiology, reported that the number of cases confirmed by Covid-19 rose to 405. While five deaths and 1,219 suspected cases were reported.

Why Covid-19 might end until September-October in Mexico? Why within ~6 months? Isn't that way too much?

And why the maximum peak is predicted in August?

If someone could explain please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would 6 months be too much?

Comment: The South American countries are being poorly advised or run by politicians.

Comment: COVID-19 isn't going to end in six months; I'll be surprised if it's gone in 12 months. I think this is simply a case of a politician trying to explain things in layman's terms and not getting it quite right. I believe what he means is the peak of the epidemic will be over in Mexico by then and it will be on the downsloping side of the infection curve.

Comment: @GrahamChiu Time to review your geography. ;-) Mexico is in North America.

Comment: Perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_America ?

Comment: Nope, it's not considered part of Central America either, which the wiki map shows. Mexico is definitely considered part of the North American continent (and so is Central America, actually).

Comment: @BryanKrause it's practically half a year. This means the chances of catching the virus in the meantime are _very_ high. And I wonder, why? In china they could manage the situation in practically 3 months. I thought this thing would end in ~2 months

Comment: No one else is controlling it the way China did, and it's also not gone from China either because cases keep coming back from the rest of the world.